# Can I use the word "respectively" for this sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

Dunn (19xx) in Germany, Duran & Centano (20xx) in XYYX, and  Zukal et al. (20xx) in Katerinska Chekoslovakia found two species of fungi, respectively.

What I am trying to say is: each of the researchers found two species in different places.

Comment: No. Say that each of them found two species of fungi.

Comment: ".....each independently discovered two  species of fungi" - sounds better to me for a science paper.

Answer (score 1):

Circumstances have complicated your task.  *Respectively* cannot help your phrasing, since that word lines up two lists of equal length, and you only have one list.  *Each* doesn't quite work either.  At least if you're talking about six species, two discovered in each of three places.  The reason is that there at least six mycologists -- Dunn is one, Duran and Centano make three, Zukal makes four, and the *et al.* (*and others*) implies that there are at least two beside Zukal on Zukal's team.  Try this

> Dunn discovered two fungus species in Germany in 1999, as did the duo
>   Duran and Centano and the team of Zuakl et al., in Puerto Rico in 2013
>   and in the Czech Republic in 2010, respectively

Comment: That will be more complicated because what you have written is not appropriate with the scientific journal format. Thanks for your help, but please do not change the format I have put.

Comment: Well, you've got a choice.  You can be simpler and ambiguous or more complicated and clear.  Which do you think is more "appropriate" for a scientific journal?